# Renew US licence while I am in India, as travelling to US in few days

Tags: driving-license

Am going to Dellas, US on 13th Jan 2015. But my Driving Licence of US has expired on 6th Jan 2015. How can I renew it and how long it will take for renewal? Can I use this licence till the time I get the renewed licence?

Comment: Welcome to expatriates.SE. This may be state specific and also dependent on your current visa.

Comment: Even renewing your license from India is *possible*, it definitely won't happen in the next 5 days. You will have to renew it when you are in the US. If you have a Texas license, you will need to visit a DPS office in Dallas.

Comment: Without knowing for certain that this is a Texas driving license, or the exact residency of the OP, there is no clear answer.